# Navigation from one List to another on different page in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to navigate from one page to another on click of list from first page to second. When i click on list on First page i navigates to second page but on second page List is not coming.

i am filling data into both the list through JSON model. On first page the data is coming but on second its not. Please help me find the solution to it.

This is my contoller of second page....

```
onInit: function() {
    var model2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    data1 = [
            {categories: "Laptop Case"},
            {categories: "USB Stick 16 GB"},
            {categories: "Webcam"},
            ];
    model2.setData({shopping1:data1});
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(model2,'idModel2');
},
```

This is the view part of my second page...

```
createContent : function(oController) {
    return new sap.m.Page('idMasterpage1',{
        showHeader:true,
        showNavButton:true,
        navButtonPress:function(oControlEvent){
            var app=sap.ui.getCore().byId('idSplitApp');
            app.to('idmasterPage1');
        },
        content: [
                    new sap.m.List('MainList1',{
                    headerText: 'ACCESSORIES',
                    path:'/shopping1',
                    items: {
                          template:new sap.m.ObjectListItem("idListtest",{
                              title:'{categories}',
                              type:"Navigation",  
                           }),  
                    },
                    })
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code that should work:

```
onInit: function() {
    var model2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    data1 = [
            {categories: "Laptop Case"},
            {categories: "USB Stick 16 GB"},
            {categories: "Webcam"},
            ];
    model2.setData({shopping1:data1});
    this.getView().setModel(model2,'idModel2');
},

createContent : function(oController) {
    return new sap.m.Page('idMasterpage1',{
        showHeader:true,
        showNavButton:true,
        navButtonPress:function(oControlEvent){
            var app=sap.ui.getCore().byId('idSplitApp');
            app.to('idmasterPage1');
        },
        content: [
                    new sap.m.List('MainList1',{
                    headerText: 'ACCESSORIES',
                    items: {
                          path:'idModel2>/shopping1',
                          template:new sap.m.ObjectListItem("idListtest",{
                              title:'{idModel2>categories}',
                              type:"Navigation"
                           }),  
                    },
                    })
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: try binding this : title:'{idModel2>categories}'

Comment: Pretty sure "path" should be inside "items"